# How can I pass and use array in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ado.net

In my stored procedure I need to select based on the user input

The query would be like this

```
SELECT A,B FROM MYTABLE WHERE B=array[0] OR B=array[1] OR B=array[2]
```

The number of items in array is unknown to me. The user selection will decide the number of elements in the array.

How can I achieve this? If I could do this, I could avoid using same procedure for each elements in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of array you can create an [User Defined Table type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.type_name AS TABLE 
(
    column1 INT NOT NULL
)
```

Pass a single columned `DataTable` from page as parameter (values are same as in that array) .

And in procedure you can use it as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name
    @array dbo.type_name READONLY
AS
   SELECT A,B FROM MYTABLE WHERE B IN (select column1 from @array)
```

Comment: whats the usage of `type_name`?

Comment: its just a name.. user defined name of that table type

Comment: thing to take care is, you must pass the datatble from page as parameter having the same columns and names as of that table type

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [Use Table-Valued Parameters (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

> Table-valued parameters are declared by using user-defined table
>   types. You can use table-valued parameters to send multiple rows of
>   data to a Transact-SQL statement or a routine, such as a stored
>   procedure or function, without creating a temporary table or many
>   parameters.

Further to that, you might want to pass it as an XML parameter, and then convert that to a table in the SP. [Using XML in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190936%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

You could even pass in a delimited string, and split that into a table [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: Passing XML as varchar to Stored Procedure, Then converting it to table value pair. right?

Comment: But how can I use those table-value pairs in the above WHERE condition?

Comment: You will probably have to use it in conjunction with ROW_NUMBER http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.105).aspx and assign it to variables, or use sub selects.

Comment: If I could do innerjoin this keyvalue pairs with the above select query, the result would be as we expected.right?
But Can I Innerjoin?

Comment: You could do inner join, or IN sub select.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please, get comma seprated string from array, is like that "12,23,25,256". Finally execute
as per below :
where @array_string is parameter of string of array:

SELECT A,B FROM MYTABLE WHERE B in(@array_string);
```

Comment: please add some description along with code so that's easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Send comma separated String instead of array

```
DECLARE @array0 VARCHAR(MAX)
--Commaseprated string array0
DECLARE @tmpArray0 TABLE ( value1 VARCHAR(500) )
--table for Commaseprated string array0

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @tmpArray0) > 0 
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO @tmpArray1
                SELECT  SUBSTRING(@array0, 1, ( CHARINDEX(',', @array0) - 1 ))
        SET @array0 = SUBSTRING(@array0, CHARINDEX(',', @array0) + 1,
                                LEN(@array0))
    END

DECLARE @array1 VARCHAR(MAX)
--Commaseprated string array1
DECLARE @tmpArray1 TABLE ( value1 VARCHAR(500) )
--table for Commaseprated string array1

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @array1) > 0 
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO @tmpArray1
                SELECT  SUBSTRING(@array1, 1, ( CHARINDEX(',', @array1) - 1 ))
        SET @array1 = SUBSTRING(@array1, CHARINDEX(',', @array1) + 1,
                                LEN(@array1))
    END


DECLARE @array2 VARCHAR(MAX)
--Commaseprated string array2
DECLARE @tmpArray2 TABLE ( value1 VARCHAR(500) )
--table for Commaseprated string array2

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @array2) > 0 
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO @tmpArray2
                SELECT  SUBSTRING(@array2, 1, ( CHARINDEX(',', @array2) - 1 ))
        SET @array2 = SUBSTRING(@array2, CHARINDEX(',', @array2) + 1,
                                LEN(@array2))
    END


SELECT  A ,
        B
FROM    MYTABLE
WHERE   B IN ( SELECT   value1
               FROM     @tmpArray0 AS ta )
        OR B IN ( SELECT    value1
                  FROM      @tmpArray1 AS ta )
        OR B IN ( SELECT    value1
                  FROM      @tmpArray2 AS ta )
```